# Logging an HTTP header in nginx access logs that contains a dot (period)

Tags: nginx, logging

I have a custom header "`AB.CD`". I want to log this header value in my nginx access logs.

This is the log format that I want to try in nginx.conf :

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" "$http_AB.CD" '
```

However the dot (period) seems to be unacceptable. I tried escaping it also, but of no use. It logs the data as  `... "-" "-.CD"`

What is the right way of logging a header that has a dot in it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a "dot" is a valid character in header names, but none of the standard values have them. I think your life will be easier if you use a different character.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try `${http_ab.cd}`

Comment: @Tim I agree. But until I get to change it.

Comment: @AlexeyTen: Thanks, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Although the period is indeed a [valid character for an HTTP header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19028068/2657515), it appears that nginx is not able to handle it correctly. This goes beyond simply logging the value to a file.

Before trying to log this custom header, make sure the header is actually available to be logged! In this case, it appears that nginx does **not** recognize this as being a valid header.

Try setting a custom header and running this simple PHP script with the following (example from [php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)):

```
<?php
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value<br/>\n";
}
```

This will display a readable list of all the headers in the request.

Now, using these web developer tools, I attempted to set a custom HTTP header with a period:

- [Modify Header Value (HTTP Headers) 0.1.3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value/) *(Firefox)*
- [Modify Headers 0.7.1.1.1-signed.1-signed](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/?src=ss) *(Firefox)*
- [HTTP Header Mangler 1.1.2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-header-mangler/) *(Firefox)*
- [Advanced REST client 9.14.64.305-stable](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) *(Chrome)*

Each of these tools behaved the same way: HTTP headers with normal names (like `AB-CD`) worked as expected; HTTP headers with names like `AB.CD` or `AB%CD` were not recognized by nginx, and were not shown in the output of the above script.

The above applies to `nginx-1.10.3`, `nginx-1.11.8`, `nginx-1.12.0`, and `nginx-1.13.1`.

Comment: Appreciate your effort investigating the thing. However, this isn't an answer to the query - and yes, of course, the header is available to be logged!

Comment: OK. So, the header is available to be logged. Does that mean it shows up in the output of `getallheaders()`? How does the header get set in your environment?  Is it done by a third-party app, a script, or some plugin?

Comment: Yes, it does. How does the source matter at all? No - It is not set by any 3rd party app.

Comment: The source does not matter for your end result (logging). But this is an interesting problem, and I am currently unable to investigate further, because I am unable to even _set_ headers like this from _any_ source. It would help me further diagnose the problem.

Comment: Use a Rest Client chrome plugin. You can send any header you'd want to.

Comment: I've updated the answer with new information: even with the Rest Client in Chrome, headers with names like `AB.CD` or `AB%CD` are still not sent correctly (at least, they are not available in the PHP script through `getallheaders()`). Every other custom header with normal characters works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `escape` parameter in your log format:

From the [nginx documentation]:[1](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

```
The escape parameter (1.11.8) allows setting json or default
characters escaping in variables, by default, default escaping
is used.
```

Comment: It didn't work. i.e. I was able to translate my logs to a json format, but it continues to use the period as a concatenation operator and does not escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is all well and good, but the ultimate source of truth is the source code, and potentially it can even be easier to find what you are after that way.  Or not - YMMV.

The `ngx_http_log_compile_format()` function in http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.c is the bit that parses your `log_format` directive.

```
1603               if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
1604                         || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
1605                         || (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
1606                         || ch == '_')
1607                     {
1608                         continue;
1609                     }
1610 
1611                     break;
```

So that bit is clear enough - the variable name in your log_format directive can only contain alphanumeric plus '_'.

That's not the end of story though, because there's still the question of how a header containing a '.' is mapped into a variable name.

http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/ngx_http_parse.c does the parsing in  `ngx_http_parse_header_line()`.  There's a bit more to read than I really want to go into though.  It appears that if the code hits a '.' in the field name, nothing gets done to the hash of the field name.  `r->invalid_header = 1;` gets set, but it doesn't `return NGX_HTTP_PARSE_INVALID_HEADER;` as in some other cases.  (see code lines 922-982).

I don't care to go on to exploring via the code as to what `r->invalid_header = 1;` does, and it doesn't seem necessary. `log_format ... ${http_abcd} ...` might work, and if that doesn't work, then I doubt anything will.  I'd just try it, and if that doesn't work, assume nothing will.